# Why it isn't circle?

Tags: javascript, graphics, 2d, geometry, curve

I'm learning about 2D graphics and I'm trying to draw circle, but I get some strange curve.

```
function rotatePoint (point, centerPoint, theta) {
    point[0] = point[0] - centerPoint[0];
    point[1] = point[1] - centerPoint[1];
    point[0] = point[0]*Math.cos(theta)-point[1]*Math.sin(theta);
    point[1] = point[0]*Math.sin(theta)+point[1]*Math.cos(theta);
    point[0] = point[0] + centerPoint[0];
    point[1] = point[1] + centerPoint[1];
}
```

Formula seems fine, but... I don't know, I can't figure it out :/ ... Thanks for help.
http://jsfiddle.net/nQvGT/173/

Comment: Perhaps you're passing the angle in degrees.  Javascript wants radians.  So theta doesn't range from 0-360; it's 0-2pi

Comment: Nope. `rotatePoint(d, [400, 400], Math.PI*n/180);` or `rotatePoint(d, [400, 400], n);` - no difference

Comment: Then Guffa's answer is likely to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing one value and then using that in the calculation of the other value. You have to first calculate both values using the original values, then set them:

```
var p0 = point[0]*Math.cos(theta)-point[1]*Math.sin(theta);
var p1 = point[0]*Math.sin(theta)+point[1]*Math.cos(theta);
point[0] = p0;
point[1] = p1;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/nQvGT/174/